# How to select distinct values from query and concatenate into one column

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I've got a table with a `category` column. Along with the selection of the clients, I'd like to select on each row the *possible* values of the category - that is, all the unique values of category in that subset.

My table looks like this:

```
| id | name          | category    |
------------------------------------
| 1  | Test Client   | Retail      |
| 2  | Test Client 2 | Corporate   |
| 3  | Test Client 3 | Retail      |
| 4  | Test Client 4 | Retail      |
| 5  | Test Client 5 | Leisure     |
```

I thought GROUP_CONCAT would do the trick:

```
SELECT `client`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT client.category) AS possible_categories
FROM (`client`)
WHERE  `name`  LIKE '%query%'
GROUP BY `client`.`id`
```

...but it just gives me that row's category, not the others.

I can do it in code, but it's an **O(n)** operation and I'd rather save on the processing time. Here's how I could do it in code, for illustrative purposes:

```
return array_unique(array_map(function($client)
{
    return $client->category;
}, $clients));
```

The ideal scenario would be to see a table like this:

```
| id | name          | category    | possible_categories     |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Test Client   | Retail      | Retail,Corporate,Leisure |
| 2  | Test Client 2 | Corporate   | Retail,Corporate,Leisure |
| 3  | Test Client 3 | Retail      | Retail,Corporate,Leisure |
| 4  | Test Client 4 | Retail      | Retail,Corporate,Leisure |
| 5  | Test Client 5 | Leisure     | Retail,Corporate,Leisure |
```

Comment: It maybe helpful if you add table definition and sample data to your question.

Comment: In that table, 'id' looks like the primary key? Correct, if so how can GROUP BY do anything? It will always be one 'row per group'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the possible categories for the matching names:-

```
SELECT `client`.*, Sub1.possible_categories
FROM (`client`)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT client.category) AS possible_categories FROM (`client`) WHERE  `name`  LIKE '%query%') Sub1
WHERE  `name`  LIKE '%query%'
```

Note the leading wildcard in the LIKEs will probably make it run slowly.

Answer (score 0):

If by "possible categories" you mean *all* categories, then you need to calculate them separately and add them in:

```
SELECT `client`.*, cc.possible_categories
FROM `client` cross join 
     (select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT client.category) AS possible_categories
      from `client`
      where `name`  LIKE '%query%'
     ) cc
WHERE  `name`  LIKE '%query%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you:

```
SELECT id, name, category, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(distinct category) FROM Client) AS possible_categories
FROM client
```

See the **[demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c8fe/15)**.